# Global Pointer in C is not updating correctly

Tags: c

I am doing a school assignment and I am stuck on my global variable for a linked list. Based on the requirements, I have a main function that calls a loadFile() function. This function checks takes input and tokenizes it, then it adds words to the linked list. The loadFile() function calls a insert() function that creates a node and adds it to the list. This issue is that the list works fine if I print from the loadFile() function, but does not work right if I try to print from the main function. I have the head of the node as a global variable but this does not seem to work.

```
Node  **headNode = NULL;
Node  **curr = NULL;

Boolean insert( char *new_string ){
Node *temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
temp->item = new_string;
if(headNode == NULL){
  temp->next = NULL;
  headNode = &temp;  
}
else{
  temp->next = (*headNode);
  headNode = &temp;
}
return true;
}

void loadFile()
{
 #define LINE_SIZE 256
  char input[LINE_SIZE];
  char *token = NULL;

  while ( fgets( input, LINE_SIZE, stdin ) )
  {
     // parse the data into separate elements
     token = strtok( input, " \t\n" );
     while ( token )
     {
       insert( token ); 

       token = strtok( NULL, " \t\n" );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely in the line:

```
temp->item = new_string;
```

`new_string` is a pointer that is local to `loadFile`. When you return from `loadFile`, the pointer is invalid.

Replace it with

```
temp->item = strdup(new_string);
```

`strdup` is not a standard library function but you can implement it very easily. Look it up on the net.

Comment: Did you say `strdup` is _not_ a standard library function?  As I'm sure you already know, it's part of POSIX 1003.1, so I'm guessing, maybe, you need some sleep? ;-)

Comment: @CraigEstey: Yes, the C Standard does *not* define `strdup()`.

Comment: It is always better to use malloc + memcpy than strdup, since the former two are C standard and also faster than strdup.

Comment: @alk Sorry, but the C spec lost control of the standard for libc to POSIX over two decades ago.  Virtually every libc implements POSIX not ISO.

Comment: @Lundin I hate to repeat myself, but the C spec lost control of the standard for libc to POSIX over two decades ago. Virtually every libc implements POSIX not ISO.  And, malloc/memcpy is only faster than strdup _if_ you already have the length, which implies [herein] that you've done a strlen first.  For my code base, I have an "xstrdup" [inline] that takes a "len" argument and does the malloc/memcpy for the speed reason you mentioned.  About a week ago, I rewrote a newbie's code that was trying to do the malloc/memcpy and blowing it.  Showed him strdup and response was "wow, thanks"

Comment: @CraigEstey Who said anything about POSIX or even an operative system? Not the OP. There's a whole world outside your sheltered desktop reality, that also uses C programming. As for newbies, they are supposed to blow everything up. You'll do them a favour explaining _why_ their code blew up.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed it like you said on the question and changed  my global variable back to single pointers. That seems to have fixed my problem.

Comment: @Lundin My last project was a C based OS that had to fit inside 128KB inside an FPGA.  kernel/drivers/realtime/roms.  And, I often explain--the case in point was an explanation in the given context.  There are multiple ways to teach.  If the OP code is far off the mark, full rewrite [with annotation] is often the better way.  Depends on context

Answer (score 2):

Your global variables should be node pointers, not pointers to node pointers. here:

```
headNode = &temp;
```

you assign the address of a local variable. That variable goes out of scope immediately after returning from the function and invalidates the head pointer. If your global head were just a pointer, you'd do

```
headNode = temp;
```

and correctly assign the handle to the freshly allocated memory to your head.

The idea to use a pointer to node pointer probably comes from a confusion with node insertion code that passes the head as an argument. In that case, the signature would look like this:

```
void insert(Node **head, const char *item);
```

You would then pass the address of a (possibly local) head pointer:

```
Node *head = NULL;

insert(&head, "banana");
```

In that case, the local head from the calling function gets modified via the pointer to node pointer – in the `insert` function, `head` is the address of the node pointer `head` *in the calling function*. Note that the head of the linked list in the calling code is still just a node pointer.

In your case, where you have only one list with a global head, your head should also be just a node pointer. There's no need to alter the the head through a pointer to node ponter; there is just one head and you can use it directly and unambigupously.